# How to add today script right after a div

Tags: javascript

I would like to put the current date right after section id=today (before H1).

Anyone can help?

Thanks

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = '<span class=updated>Updated ' + mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + '</span>';
document.write(today);
```

```css
.updated {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="today">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the parent element using `document.getElementById("today")` and then use the `prepend`

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = 'Updated ' + mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'updated';

span.textContent = today;
document.getElementById("today").prepend(span);
```

```css
.updated {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section id="today">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `insertAfter()` method maybe ?

```
var todaySection = document.getElementById("today");

todaySection.insertAfter(today);
```

Article : https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-insertafter/